# .js libraries rails help (WOW and parallax window). Had 3rd party build layout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I hired someone to do the layout for a project I was doing.  I've been implementing it into Rails and have a few problems/errors.
url: http://mygrupz-app.herokuapp.com/

First. wow.js is not loading.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
```

Second. No Parallax Window.  Images not loading.

Third. Datepicker working on localhost but not working on Heroku.

If you have any help with any of these it'd be greatly appreciated.  Thanks all!

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jqueryy_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require_tree
```

application.css

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
*/
```

Comment: Fix the typo `jqueryy_ujs`. Then, run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally, see if any errors come up

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice on the production bundle exec rake.  I did that earlier and that fixed a lot of css problems.

As to my original question, stupid me.  Didn't have all the javascript files loaded into the assets/javascripts directory.  After that everything worked.

Still having issue with the datepicker...